# Use of glob to generate a list of target files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read from about 700 directories and sub-directories to create a list of Word documents (subsequently the list will be filtered for keywords). I'm using glob in the way shown below and whilst this works it is very slow. A single directory is taking about 6 minutes to read which means reading 700 of them is not going to be feasible.

```
target_files = glob.glob(f'//companyserver.com/Projects/{number[0:5]}XXX/{number}*/**/*.[Dd][Oo][Cc][Xx]', recursive = True)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It seems that you're searching paths on a remote file server. Consider using some `sftp` clients which have `list/scan` methods for matching files.

Comment: I would expect [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to perform better than `glob`. However, if bandwidth is the limiting factor, it will buy you little.